# Locate Store View HTML

Tags: magento-1.9

I am looking for the file to edit the HTML for https://cashino.kellyseye.com/

I would like to change the static block "home-center-promotion" to display another static block.

Thanks

Comment: You can edit statick block from Admin >> Cms >> Static Bloks